# Amazon Redshift and performance on delete

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have two tables in Redshift - `t1` and `t2`.

`t2` already contains ~300 000 000 records.

`t1` contains ~10 000 000 records.

I need to delete all records from `t1` which are already present in `t2` based on `id` field.

In order to do this, I'm going to execute the following queries(one of them):

```
DELETE FROM t1 WHERE id IN(SELECT id FROM t2);
```

or

```
DELETE FROM t1 USING t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.ud;
```

or

```
DELETE FROM t1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t2 WHERE  t1.id = t2.id);
```

Before I'll do it on real data, I'd like to ask - is it a good idea to use such queries in Redshift from performance point of view or there are some other (better) techicues there for such case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The biggest performance factor to doing this will be the distribution of t1 and t2, not the query construct.  Are these tables key based distribution of the column id?

That being said I'd recommend that you go with the "delete using" construct.  All of these queries join t1 and t2 together and doing this on the native tables is best.  The Redshift query planner should see through the sub-selects in the other 2 queries but why run the risk of it missing an optimization.

Remember that when this complete a vacuum (delete only) / analyze would be recommended (at the end of all the transforms being run).  Since both of these actions are now automated (if enabled) you should be covered but if you are adding data into t1 after the delete you will want a full vacuum at an appropriate point.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I can choose the DISTKEY for both of these tables. Right now both of them are EVENly distributed but I can change it to be destributed by `id` column. From your expirience, in case of `id DISTKEY` in both tables and mentioned numbers of rows, how long DELETE process can take? On appropriate Redshift cluster. Is it a seconds, or minutes or hours of work?

Comment: This will be fast - seconds.  300 million rows and 10 million rows are on the smaller side for Redshift.  The speed will depend on the cluster size / type as well as sort key.  Scanning 300M rows for one column will take a little bit but with each slice reading in parallel this can be sped up with cluster size.  Then hashing for the join and joining can take a bit but again parallelism is your friend.  Analyzing your tables and choosing appropriate sort keys will help too.